# C# gives anonymous error

Tags: c#

while i am calling a method which is declared in another project. calling project and called project are presented in same solution.

I am getting a error window that says:

Window Tile : Test.vshost.exe

Test.vshost.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. we are sorry for the inconvenience.

(I will make disappear the error window by clicking "Dont Send" button)

what is the reason for such this error.

Note: I have included the refereed project in reference.

I used call a methode as follows

```
ReconcileDBService.InsertRecordInT_AUDIT_Incident(keyCase);
```

Above methode declared as follows

```
public static void InsertRecordInT_AUDIT_Incident(string keyCase)
```

Comment: Does anything show in the Output window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please post the code, without that it would be extremely difficult to determine what's actually happening.

Comment: Have you checked your event log for more info

Comment: where i can check the event log. you mean os's event viewer. if so, i checked and found that "Faulting application test.vshost.exe, version 9.0.21022.8, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, fault address 0x00012afb." - This what i found

Comment: code is very simple: you assume a solution contains two project as x and y. i am calling a method which declared in y from x. that it.

Comment: but one more point is  i am calling that method(static) from inside a thread.

Comment: Anyone have a quick link to proper exception handling in .Net?  I think a simple try-catch block in that static method will do wonders for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really help you based on the data you provide...

Is your program using Win32 or COM interop ?

Try to add breakpoints and debug messages to pinpoint the problem. Once you know the exact location where the problem occurs, it will be easier to understand it.

Comment: it is just a console application.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the "Visual Studio hosting process" and start your session again. Maybe you get some better or more information about an exception that is raised by your programm.

You can do this under the Project-Properties-->Debug-->Enable the Visual Studio hosting process (uncheck)

Also you could check the build order of your projects. It may be that the "Visual Studio hosting process" uses a diffrent assembly version than your programm expects.

Comment: Great, I able to see the what is the exact error : 

The type initializer for 'Test.ReconcileDBService' threw an exception.

Comment: i can change the build order because the project which has reffered class and method is present is not included in dependencies tab

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl-Alt-E (Debug->Exceptions) and in the 'Break when an exception is:' selection, select everything.

Start a debug session with the application.

The debugger should now stop at the crash and you should be able to look what you are sending to the other project, and maybe solve your problem.